# Rewrite GET parameters with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite get parameters on htaccess to url change like this:

`example.com/test.php?action=value1&step=value2`

to
`example.com/test/value1/value2`

I tried with:

```
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2
```

But it's not working.. I already have enabled apache2 rewrite..

How i can do that??

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Ok, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?action=$2&step=$3 [L]
```

Comment: It worked but if i remove the last /, i get 404.

Comment: @kanohn, could you please do let me know if you have your test.php is present in same path where .htaccess is present? Thank you.

Comment: @kanohn, try changing last rule to `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ 
 /$1.php?action=$2&step=$3 [L]` and try once? Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs

Comment: Thanks for the help but its doesn't works yet if i remove the last /.. still get 404, i'm cleaning my cache.

Comment: i found this link that worked but have some way to do that for all files at once? https://www.taniarascia.com/rewrite-query-string-to-path-with-htaccess/

Comment: @kanohn, my mentioned rules are generic it should work for all non existing directories and files, please let me know on same.

Comment: Yes i tried your rules but still get 404 without /

Comment: @kanohn, ok 404 means its not able to find your php files(and may be rewriting fine with these rules), could you please do let me know path where htaccess exists? And where your ,php files are present(I know you told in previous comments but want to know if you have all phps present in same path?), kindly confirm on same once.